# Read many text files into SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, linq, database-design, database-connection, sql-server-express

I'm very new to SQL Server Express in C#.

I have a directory of 2000 text files and I want to read it into a database line by line and save the file path, line number and text of the line. What's the best way, Linq-to-SQL, or connection string?

I used the below this just keep looping I assume it might be because it takes so long to read to the database

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mchotu\Desktop\Sample data", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
                {
                    string s;
                    int line = 0;

                    while((s=sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
                    {
                        db.textFilesCompletes.InsertOnSubmit(new textFilesComplete() { fileNameone = file });
                        db.textFilesCompletes.InsertOnSubmit(new textFilesComplete() { text = s });
                        db.textFilesCompletes.InsertOnSubmit(new textFilesComplete() { Linenumber = line });
                    }

                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }                
        }
        this.textFilesCompleteTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.textFilesComplete);// this displays the updated table
}   //ends function
```

Is this something that can be read to quickly?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **concrete database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1):

you are not creating `textFilesComplete` correctly. Your correct solution should be like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] ls = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mchotu\Desktop\Sample data", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach(string file in ls)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
                {
                    string s;
                    int line = 0;

                    while((s=sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
                    {
                        db.textFilesCompletes.InsertOnSubmit(new textFilesComplete() { fileNameone = file ,text = s ,Linenumber = line });

                    }

                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }                
        }
        // dont know what your doing here?
        this.textFilesCompleteTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.textFilesComplete);
}
```

By the way a better solution for loading text files is by using `SqlBulkCopy` [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its usage can be simplified by utilizing something like `ObjectDataReader` [Documentation & download](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ObjectDataReader-8476dd72)

This exposes `IEnumerable<T>` as an `IDataReader`

Here is a working example.

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\data\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    using(SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(@"Server=.\SQLExpress; Database= AAA; Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.textFilesCompletes";
        sbc.EnableStreaming = true;
        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            int lineNumber = 1;
            var lines = from a in File.ReadLines(file,Encoding.Default)
                        select new {FileName = file,Text = a,LineNumber = lineNumber++};
            sbc.WriteToServer(lines.AsDataReader() );               

        }
    }
```